# Possible to modify 'whitespace-display-mappings' at runtime?

Tags: whitespace, display, buffer-display-table

Making changes to `whitespace-display-mappings` while emacs runs doesn't seem to do anything.

```
(setq
 whitespace-display-mappings
 '(
   (space-mark 32 [183] [46]) ; middle-dot
   (tab-mark 9 [9654 9] [92 9]) ; arrow
  )
 )
```

Then later on:

```
(setq whitespace-display-mappings '())
```

Is there a way to refresh the display mapping so key bindings can be used to change which whitespace is displayed?

Comment: Try evaluating `(whitespace-display-char-on)` -- it is a non-interactive function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning whitespace off then on worked for me.  Just evaluate these two functions with `M-x eval-expression` or `M-:`:

```
(whitespace-display-char-off)
(whitespace-display-char-on)
```